# Examples of methods for solving modular equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Simple mod questions. Can you show example to do such things?

1. $x+40 \equiv 1 \pmod{88}$.
2. $x \cdot 40 \equiv 1 \pmod{88}$.
3. $5a+3b \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ and $2a+b \equiv 7 \pmod{11}$.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you know about modular arithmetic? Once we know that, M.SE can help more easily.

Comment: To do what? I assume you mean to solve?

Answer (score 6):

Solving modular equations is mostly just like solving ordinary equations.

How do you solve $7x + 6 = 20$?

$$\begin{align}7x+6 &= 20
\\ 7x &= 20 - 6 = 14
\\ x &= 14 \cdot \frac{1}{7} = 2
\hspace{15.4em}
\end{align}$$

Now, how do you solve $7x+6 = 20 \bmod 29$?

$$\begin{align}7x+6 &\equiv 20 & \pmod{29}
\\ 7x &\equiv 20 - 6 \equiv 14& \pmod{29}
\\ x &\equiv 14 \cdot \frac{1}{7} \equiv 14 \cdot 25 \equiv 350 \equiv 2 & \pmod{29} \end{align}$$

(or, in this case, just note that $14/7 = 2$, although the calculation usually isn't so obvious)

One of the main differences is that you can't use long division, and need to use a new algorithm to divide: e.g. you can use the extended euclidean algorithm to compute the reciprocal of any element. Presumably your book has shown you this.

Although with such small numbers, trial and error works fine too.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: @jsdlmfskfl: If you don't understand things at all, the usual approach would to be to read a textbook or other introductory source on the material, and turn to a Q&A site when you have more focused questions.

Comment: @Hurkyl Ok, how did you get this row(s): $7x=1=20-6=14$? Where did $1=14$ came from? I guess this is just a mistake,.. unless you, for some unknown reason, changed to $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$. :)

Comment: @quapka: Huh, what an odd typo.

Comment: Where does the 25 come from?

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson 25 is the modular inverse of 7 with modulo 29.